# Substitute IP using sed or awk from xml which contains square brakets

Tags: xml, bash, awk, replace, square-bracket

I have this code which is would like to change the IP from:

```
<mailHost>[10.237.30.150]:25</mailHost>
```

and I need to change to another IP:
Expected result:

```
<mailHost>[10.237.30.151]:25</mailHost>
```

Here is what I have tried but still giving an error and does not change anything.

```
sed -n "/<mailHost>/ {s/10.237.30.150/10.237.30.151/}" file
```

Any hint would be really welcome :)
Thank you.

Comment: Don't parse XML with non syntax aware tools - use `xmlstartlet` or `xmllint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear (are you trying to replace any IP anywhere it occurs or just that specific IP or that specific IP just in that context or any IP in that context or something else?) but this **may** be what you want:

```
$ sed 's/\(<mailHost>\[\)[^]]*/\110.237.30.151/' file
<mailHost>[10.237.30.151]:25</mailHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -v value="new_value" '/mailHost/{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);if(val){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);next}} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to make the changes in Input_file itself then do add following in above command `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file`.

Adding a non-one liner form of explanation too now.

```
awk -v value="new_value" '
/mailHost/{
    match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
    if(val){
       print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH);
       next}
}
1'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) using awk is a really good alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "s/10.237.30.150/10.237.30.151/g" file
```

This will not work?

Comment: Too wild. As some other entries which also have this IP would be affected. Thank you btw.